# UITableView stopped scrolling on 7.1 devices

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7.1

During the app development I have the deployment target set to 8 and when everything is done, I changed the deployment target to 7.1 and started testing on 7.1 device. The TableView is no longer scrollable. Interestingly also the Back Button stopped responding. I tested the same app on 8.3 simulator and on 8.0 device, its working as expected. Not sure why? Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things to fix this. There were some posts which suggested to do the following self.myTableView.bounces = YES; and others of this kind but none of them helped me. I re-created a new XIB file and made the old classes to become the owners of this and that solved the issue. Hope this might help some one facing the same issue.